# Asynchronously load content with unknown MIME type (image or text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for a way to asynchronously load an image with javascript/jquery while, at the same time, be able to handle a returning xml document (in case of an error).

At the moment I load the image like this:

```
var img = $("<img id='ws-image'/>").attr('src', $("#dynImgUrl").val());

img.load(function() {
    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined"
                       || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
        alert('broken image!');
    } else {
        img.attr('width', 500);
        img.attr('height', 500);
        $("img-div").html(img);
    }
}).error(function() {
    alert("Could not load image");
});
```

This does work as long as the server returns an image. If, in case of an error, it returns a xml document, the error callback is called. But I need to get the content of that xml document and don't know how.

Is there a way to be able to handle both types of possible server responses?

Thank you!

Comment: To avoid running into problems later, do not set the src attribute until after you bind to the load event. Is your url a cross-domain url?

Comment: I don't get it, are you saying `$("#dynImgUrl").val()` could be the URL to an image, and it could also be XML. I don't really see any async stuff?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments. The url is a cross-domain url or at least, I cannot influence the server's behaviour, if that's what you were asking.

Yes, the URL is an URL to a Web Service which returns an image of no error occurs. If an error occurs it will respond with a xml document. I need to be able to display that content, too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server has CORS enabled to allow cross-domain Ajax, I would attempt to load the image, and then do an Ajax fetch for the same resource if the image load fails.

Alternatively, if a second pass to the server is unacceptable, you could do a fetch of the resource, encode it in base 64 (using [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa)) and show the image from a [`data:` URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Then, do the same error-checking you do here, and refer back to the original Ajax result in the event of image failure.

Comment: Hey apsillers! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, a second fetch for the same resource is unacceptable, because the server might recompute everything (which might take a minute or so) before it finally returns the xml error document. Your second approach seems like something I would like to do. I will try it out and see if it does what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find a way to correctly base64 encode the raw image data. I tried to do something like this:
`$.ajax({
          url : $("#dynImgUrl").val(),
          success : function(data) {
            var img = $("<img id='ws-image'/>").attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + window.btoa(data));
...`
But the window.btoa call results in an InvalidCharacterError.